# how to jump back to the previous edit place

Tags: vim

Is it possible to go back to the previous edit place in vim? I know using marks, one can move back and forth between different places within a file, but I don't know whether or not vim could automatically remember the previous edit place for you.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The last change is held in the mark named `.` so you can jump to the mark with <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (backtick, dot) or <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (apostrophe, dot).  See:

```
:help mark-motions
:help '.
```

Answer (score 104):

I use the following (from the documentation):

```
g;          Go to [count] older position in change list.

g,          Go to [count] newer cursor position in change list.
```

Do `:help g,` to read more about this

Comment: awesome! I new about ` and ., but I came here looking for a way to jump to one before last change. This is it: `2g;`

Answer (score 47):

`ctrl+o`
`ctrl+i` to go forward (once you've gone backward, of course)

Comment: This uses the jumplist, so will only work if a 'jump' was used after editing.  If you just scrolled with the mouse and clicked on a new location, it'll fail.

Comment: ...and `:ju[mps]` to show the jump history (which is fixed at 100, though there is a separate jump list per window).

Comment: With all due respect, if anyone is using the mouse in Vim, they're missing the point entirely.

Comment: Can't argue with that (although I am _very_ occasionally guilty of reaching for the scroll-wheel...)

Comment: I've been vimming for 150 years and have written more vimscript than 10 Tim Popes and I still use the mouse sometimes

Answer (score 25):

To jump to the last edit position type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Does this really work? I pressed  `gi` in normal mode and it just switch to insert mode in the current cursor position.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, just goes to insert so that key sequence is not bound.

Comment: It does work, but it goes a step further than OP's ask. What this does is take you to the last edit position, and put you in insert mode. Now, if you just edited the buffer, went back into normal mode, and immediately issued `gi`, you would simply be put back into insert mode, which is pretty much the same as pressing `i`. You would have to navigate away from the current edit position and issue `gi` to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `u` then `Ctrl-r` before I learned about `'.`